# How to fix cors error from static website hosted on aws s3?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, cors

I have a static website hosted on an aws s3 bucket. I am trying to do a post request to my backend which is currently localhost. I am getting the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/login' from origin 'http://blahblah33.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

**This is my bucket policy:**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::blahblah33/*"
    }
]
```

}

**Cors policy for bucket**

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
}
```

]

**Cors policy for backend express.js**

```
const corsOptions = { 
// origin:'https://abc.onrender.com',
AccessControlAllowOrigin: '*',  
origin: "*",
methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
credentials:false
```

}

Comment: See [Private Network Access (PNA)](https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/). Unfortunately for you, Express.js's CORS middleware [doesn't support PNA yet](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/236). You'll have to either set the required headers manually or rely on another CORS middleware library altogether. Also, adding an `AccessControlAllowOrigin` property to your options object won't help.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will look into this

Answer (score -1):

You need to handle This in Backend `Express JS`

First Install This Package 
`npm i cors`

Import it in your Main `Index.js` or `App.js` file of your backend file 
`const express = require('express');` 
`const app = express();` 
`const cors = require('cors');`

and then use it 
`app.use(cors())`

OR 
For Development Purpose you can use Below chrome extension 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Comment: This does not work